# Comparing Windows with Linux/Unix

Tags: windows, unix

On Windows, C:\ is the equivalent of what on UNIX/Linux?

On Windows, C:\Users\me is the equivalent of what on UNIX/Linux?

On Windows, C:\Windows\System32 is the equivalent of what on UNIX/Linux?

Not sure about these. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\` is `/`.

`C:\Users\me` is `/home/me`.

`C:\Windows\System32` is all over the place, depending on what you are looking for.

- A lot of it lives in `/usr/bin`
- The commands that aren't used so often are in `/usr/sbin`
- configurations are in `/etc` (there is no registry as such)
- logs are in `/var/logs`
- fonts - you have to look for where XWindows is installed.  It varies depending on version
- Don't know where the drivers folder is - it just works so I don't bother with this bit

`C:\Program Files` and `C:\ProgramData` are also in `/usr/bin` or in `/var`.

Answer (score 2):

What's the equivalent of spark plugs in an electric car?

Windows and Linux are completely different. There are some similarities, but their approach to directory trees differs greatly.

On **Windows**, you have a few root directories called *drives* and designated with letters. These are typically filesystem roots too. Windows has inherited this scheme from DOS.

Windows itself is usually installed on `C:`, but it's not a must. The reason why it's usually `C:` is that `A:` and `B:` are reserved for floppy drives (also due to its DOS legacy) and the installer picks first available drive letter, that is `C:`. Other than that, `C:` doesn't have any significance. It could be any other letter as well. Only `A:` and `B:` were special, but they're not anymore. You can use them if you wish. Windows will just avoid them by default.

So basically you have drives which correspond to partitions on a physical device, each having a filesystem and storing some files.

**Linux** takes a completely different approach inherited from UNIX. There's just a single root directory called `/`. It can correspond to a filesystem on a physical device, but it could as well be stored entirely in RAM. (Actually, every time Linux boots it initially loads a small filesystem into RAM, uses it to load some drivers - storage drivers in particular - and then replaces it with an on-disk filesystem, discarding the in-memory one.)

This `/` directory can contain other files and directories. Every directory can be used to *mount* another filesystem in it. The contents of the mounted filesystem will appear as if they were contents of the directory it's mounted in, effectively creating a single directory tree that consists of multiple filesystems.

Such mounted filesystem doesn't have to be stored on a physical device too. Linux makes use of this extensively, because in the UNIX philosophy everything is a file. Devices, network sockets etc. all appear as files somewhere in the directory tree. They don't correspond to actual files on disk because that wouldn't make sense. They are provided by virtual filesystem drivers instead, which translate file reads/writes to communication with underlying devices, network target etc. So for example to print text on a printer, you could simply write to a file that represents that printer. (Reading from this file doesn't make much sense though.)

**Windows** has changed the location of its user files over time. DOS-based versions of Windows weren't designed with multiuser environments in mind, so originally there was only a single place to store user's documents. If my memory serves, it was `C:\My Documents`. Some other user-specific stuff, like list of Start menu programs, were stored in `C:\Windows` subdirectories.

NT-based versions of Windows were multiuser at their core, making use of the `C:\Users` directory. Everything that was user-specific was (expected to be) stored in its subdirectories, one for every user. In Windows XP (I think?) more special purpose directories were added inside *My Documents*: *My Pictures*, *My Music*, *My Videos*. Later, in Vista, these were moved to be stored besides *My Documents* rather than inside it. There was also some translation-related mess that I won't go into here.

**Linux** (and Unix) took the multiuser approach from the very beginning. Each user is given a subdirectory typically under `/home` (so for example I'd get `/home/gronostaj`), although other locations can be used. All user-specific files should be stored in there. Special purpose directories are configurable and specified by the XDG standard; they're not required though.

System and program files are (theoretically) nicely segregated on **Windows**, under `C:\Windows` and `C:\Program Files`. It's not that simple in practice: advent of 64-bit CPUs introduced a muddy distinction between *Program Files* and *Program Files (x86)*. There's also some lousy translation handling going on, plus some programs install into `%AppData%` (where only program configurations should reside by design) because there's no user-specific directory for software.

**Linux**, again, has a different take on this - rather than turn a clean original design into a mess like Windows did, Linux got a head start by using a messy design from the very beginning. Wikipedia has an article on [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which explains what should go where and how it has changed over time.